# .NET MAUI custom component not reflecting back the property value

Tags: custom-controls, maui

I want to create a component that can represent a phone number: country code, area code and the number.

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    [Required]
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public PhoneNumber()
    { }

    public PhoneNumber(int areaCode, string countryCode, int number)
    {
        AreaCode = areaCode;
        CountryCode = countryCode;
       Number = number;
    }
}
```

This object is nested in another object in the ViewModel.

I crated a custom component of type ContentView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:SunMeSurvey.Extensions"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Common.Data.Models.Survey;assembly=MauiCommon"
             x:Class="SunMeSurvey.UI.Controls.PhoneNumberComponent"
             x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:PhoneNumber />
    </ContentView.BindingContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <material:EditorField Title="{loc:Localize Country}"
                                  Text="{Binding CountryCode, Source={Reference this}}"
                                  Padding="10" Grid.Column="0"  />
        <material:EditorField Title="{loc:Localize Area}"
                                  Text="{Binding AreaCode, Source={Reference this}}"
                                  Padding="10" Grid.Column="1"
                                  Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        <material:EditorField Title="{loc:Localize PhoneNumber}"
                                  Text="{Binding Number, Source={Reference this}}"
                                  Padding="10"
                                  Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

code behind:

```
public partial class PhoneNumberComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CountryCodeProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CountryCode), typeof(string), typeof(PhoneNumberComponent), string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty AreaCodeProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AreaCode), typeof(int), typeof(PhoneNumberComponent), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty NumberProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Number), typeof(int), typeof(PhoneNumberComponent), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string CountryCode
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CountryCodeProperty);
        set => SetValue(CountryCodeProperty, value);
    }

    public int AreaCode
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(AreaCodeProperty);
        set => SetValue(AreaCodeProperty, value);
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(NumberProperty);
        set => SetValue(NumberProperty, value);
    }

    public PhoneNumberComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In my page I am using it like this:

```
<controls:PhoneNumberComponent CountryCode="{Binding Phase.Contact.Phone.CountryCode, BindingMode.TwoWay}"
               AreaCode="{Binding Phase.Contact.Phone.AreaCode, BindingMode.TwoWay}"
               Number="{Binding Phase.Contact.Phone.Number, BindingMode.TwoWay}" />
```

At the end, when I lookup my ViewModel on the end of the preocess, my phone number field has no values.
My guess is that the data typed in the input fields are not reflected back.

Any idea, or what am I doing wrong?!

thnx

UPDATE (the dummy test app)

**- the view model**

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string fullName;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void OnShowFullName()
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", FullName, "OK");
        });
    }
}
```

**- the dummy compontnt**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DummyMauiApp.DummyComponent"
             x:Name="this">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Name" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding FullName, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>

public partial class DummyComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FullNameProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FullName), typeof(string), typeof(DummyComponent), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string FullName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(FullNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(FullNameProperty, value);
    }

    public DummyComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**- the main page**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:component="clr-namespace:DummyMauiApp"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DummyMauiApp"
             x:DataType="viewModel:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="DummyMauiApp.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30,0"
                             VerticalOptions="Start">

            <component:DummyComponent x:Name="dummyComponent" FullName="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <Button Command="{Binding ShowFullNameCommand}" Text="Show" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel => this.BindingContext as MainPageViewModel;

    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**- the MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Now when I press the button, the FullName property of the view model is empty.

In my real scenario case, the property that I tried to bind on a component is a nested property:

```
public class UserData : UserBaseData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Elektromos mérőhelyazonosító
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("electric_meter_id")]
        [Required]
        public string ElectricMeterId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Az ügyfél az ingatlan tulajdonosa?
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("is_user_owner")]
        [Required]
        public bool IsUserOwner { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ügyféltípus
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("usertype")]
        [Required]
        public UserType UserType { get; set;}

        /// <summary>
        /// Egy háztartásban élők száma
        /// 25 év felettiek
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("residents")]
        [Required]
        public int ResidentsAbove25 { get; set; } = 1;

        /// <summary>
        /// Egy háztartásban élők száma
        /// 25 év alattiak
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("residents_under_25")]
        [Required]
        public int ResidentsUnder25 { get; set; }
    }
public class UserBaseData : BaseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ügyfélazonosító (Szolgáltató)
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstname")]
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("surname")]
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone_country_code")]
    [Required]
    public int PhoneCountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    [Required]
    public PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; } = new PhoneNumber();

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    [Required]
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public PhoneNumber()
    { }

    public PhoneNumber(int areaCode, string countryCode, int number)
    {
        AreaCode = areaCode;
        CountryCode = countryCode;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

This object is nested in another object, that is nested in top level object (just to be clear, not done by me).

Comment: there may be other problems, but the first thing I see is that you are specifying the `BindingContext` in the XAML.  You don't want to do that with a custom control

Comment: True, but still not working

Comment: If you've made a change to your code/xaml based on Jason's comment, then **update the code in question**. Otherwise, its hard to be certain exactly what code is "still not working".

Comment: Still not reflecting the typed values in component in the page binded model.

Comment: 1) Did you **update the code in question**, like I asked you to, so that we know for sure what code is running? 2) *"This object is nested in another object in the ViewModel."* Show enough of the ViewModel declaration, to see the nesting. 3) **set some initial values in the ViewModel constructor**. Do those values show up in the UI?

Comment: I made the suggested changes, and it not worked for me. So I made a dummy test app to show what I want to do. I updated my question.